# Why is my cursor offset in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using 6.0.0 Jupyter Notebook on Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). And this is happening:

[image]

This happens farther down on the page so I assume there's the line height is inaccurate.

At the top of the page, it shows correctly

[image]

Comment: did you try resetting the scale (Ctrl +0)?

Comment: This worked, thank you!